# Query string do not nor sort properly width ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this, where I want the strings concatenated as one, but I can not figure out how to make it sort correctly. This is how I I've tried. It sorts on the concated string, but I want to sort before `CONCAT`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(PlantName,' ',city,' ',address,' ',postal)as navn,id AS IdNumber
FROM AdressTable WHERE shownOrNot=1 ORDER BY PlantName ASC,city ASC
```

Comment: *but i want to sort before concat* This phrase makes no sense. Your task is absolutely unclear. Try to demonstrate (show source table data and desired result as table-typed text).

Comment: Hey, use this fiddle for your example : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hgHPCT4YEasFyNYhN52mme/0 . After update, don't forget to click 'Update' and then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62039260/edit) with the new updated fiddle link.

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. I need to do the query on the mentioned columns first and then coconcat them and return them with the id column.

Comment: Still not clear, please use the fiddle link I provide to give some example data and illustration on your expected output. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the query in your question? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks to all off you for answering. The query works fine, but my input fields not so much. Data pollution you might calll it. I apologize.